# Add Ghost32 to Hiren’s CD 15.2

Tags: boot, ghost, hiren

Hi I need add ghost32 to Hiren’s CD v15.2 Windows Mini XP.

I found this [tutorial](http://fdo-workspace.blogspot.sk/2011/03/hirens-cd-creating-ghost32uha-with.html).

My steps:

- With HBCDCustomizer I extract ISO
- Create folder C:\Ghost
- Copy Ghost32.exe and uharc.exe to C:\Ghost folder
- uharc create file Ghost32.uha
- Ghost32.uha need to be copy `..CD\HBCD\WinTools\Files`.  (from tutorial)
- But HBCD folder contains these folders:
- Boot
- Programs

  - Files
- XP
- I don’t know in which folder I need copy `Ghost32.uha` file or if I need copy Ghost32.exe or any other file somewhere.
- First I copied only `Ghost32.uha` to `..\CD\HBCD\Programs\Files`. Result in Windows Mini Xp Ghost32 is not found.
- Second attempt. Folder `Programs\Files` contains 7z files so I tried
  copy to this    folder

  - `Ghost32.uha`
  - `Ghost32.7z`
- Ghost32 is found but not work.

Any advice how add Ghost32 to Windows XP in Hiren’s CD v15.2?

Comment: Last version of hiren boot cd that contained norton ghost is 10.6 http://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v106/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

1. Download **Hirens.BootCD.15.2.zip** and unpack it to a folder (for
   example, **D:\Hirens.BootCD.15.2**).
2. Run **D:\Hirens.BootCD.15.2\HBCDCustomizer.exe**, follow steps
   **A-D** as shown on the picture and wait until extraction is done.
3. Download [Ghost 11.5.1.2269](http://rghost.net/6K2JZbRjP) or [Ghost 12.0.0.4112](http://rghost.net/6bk4g6JH2) and copy it to
   **D:\MyBootCD\CD\HBCD\Programs\Files**.
4. Follow steps **E-F** as shown on the picture and wait until image
   creation is finished.
5. Run **D:\Hirens.BootCD.15.2\BurnToCD.cmd** and burn a newly created
   image.
6. **D:\MyBootCD\MyHBCD.iso** to a blank CD.

Comment: Can you post the picture here?  It seems to be hosted on a known malware site.

Comment: Please, update the link to ghost32.7z file

Comment: Link have been updated. Please check it out.